# RoR: Chained Stub using Mocha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, mocha.js

Is it possible to stub an entire chain using Mocha? For example, I want to stub:

```
User.first.posts.find(params[:id])
```

such that it returns a predefined post instance instead of accessing the database. Ideally, I'd want to do something like:

```
@post = Post.new
User.any_instance.stubs(:posts,:find).returns(@post)
```

As you can see, I'm stubbing out both the 'posts' and 'find' methods together. Obviously this isn't working right now, but is there a way I can achieve this effect? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I found the following online which hacks a way to do this:

```
module Mocha
  module ObjectMethods
    def stub_path(path)
      path = path.split('.') if path.is_a? String
      raise "Invalid Argument" if path.empty?
      part = path.shift
      mock = Mocha::Mockery.instance.named_mock(part)
      exp = self.stubs(part)
      if path.length > 0
        exp.returns(mock)
        return mock.stub_path(path)
      else
        return exp
      end
    end
  end
end
```

With this, you can call User.any_instance.stub_path('posts.find').returns(@post)

Answer (score 2):

Based on http://viget.com/extend/stubbing-method-chains-with-mocha you can try:

```
User.stubs(:first).returns(stub(:posts => stub(:find => @post)))
```

Although I could only get this form to work:

```
find = stub
find.stubs(:find).returns(@post)
posts = stub
posts.stubs(:find).returns(find)
User.stubs(:first).returns(posts)
```

Comment: This is a very late reply, but in case it's useful to anyone... The post you linked to is a good one, but the syntax is old. Calling [stub requires a name as the first argument](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/Mocha/API.html#stub-instance_method). So stubbing, for example, `Rails.env.production?` to return `true` would be `Rails.stubs(:env).returns(stub('production?', production?: true))`

Comment: The documentation is missing something:
`User.stubs(:first).returns(stub.stubs(:posts => stub.stubs(:find => @post)))` You have to use `stub.stubs` to create the instance and then use its method.